# iOS Safari won't download a file if I set the Content-Length header

Tags: php, ios, http, safari

I have a php web-app that allows to buy and download PDF and ePub files. The download response looks like this :

```
$response->headers->set("Content-Type", $file->get('type'));
$response->headers->set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", $file->get('type'));
$response->headers->set("Content-Length", $file->get('size'));
$response->headers->set("Pragma", "no-cache");
$response->headers->set("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public");
$response->headers->set("Expires", "0");
```

Since a few weeks, users have not been able to download files using the latest Safari (I have 10.3.1) on iOS (Safari on Mac and other browsers seems to be fine). The download loads but never seems to start. If I remove the `Content-Length` header line though, the download starts instantly. I have checked that the content-length value is correct.

Any idea why this is happening on iOS Safari ? Should I just offer download without the `Content-Length` header ?